# Total function not returning value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

So i can access my array's value just fine:

```
 $scope.checkVal = myArray[0].Value;
```

I want to sum the total of Values in my array:

```
$scope.sumByYear = function () {
    var yearTotal = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        yearTotal += myArray[i].Value;
    }
    return yearTotal;
}
```

Here is my Html directive:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div> {{sumByYear | currency}} </div>
</div>
```

Nothing is returned. What am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `sumByYear` is a function you need to call it:

```
<div>{{sumByYear() | currency}}</div>
```

However if it's possible it's better to precalculated dynamic values in controller and avoid function execution in HTML.

Comment: Wow, im super lame. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please explain how to precalculate dynamic values. How would i iterate through my array if I do not create a function?

Comment: If you don't need to recalculate total later again, then you might not need a function at all. But in any case you could calculate total in controller and send this value to template: `$scope.total = $scope.sumByYear()`.

Answer (score 3):

sumByYear is function pointer instead a value so if you want to get a value you need to invoke it.

HTML (notice `yearTotal` instead of `sumByYear`, in my example):

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ClickToEditCtrl">
    <div ng-hide="editorEnabled">
      {{title}} {{ yearTotal | currency }} 
      <a href="#" ng-click="editorEnabled=!editorEnabled">Edit title</a>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="editorEnabled">
      <input ng-model="title">
      <a href="#" ng-click="editorEnabled=!editorEnabled">Done editing?</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS (again, note `yearTotal` instead of `sumByYear`):

```
function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Welcome to this demo!";
  $scope.yearTotal = 0;
  var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];    
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
       $scope.yearTotal += myArray[i];
    }               
}
```

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/1690/)

Comment: I replaced it just to show you  don't need to call the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

`sumByYear` must be `sumByYear()`. sumByYear is a function